# How to listen is context menu open in vscode extension api

Tags: vscode-extensions

I want to change context menu items in my vscode extension dynamically.

So, when the user triggers right-click I want to make some checks and generate some items in the context menu.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't see any listener for a context menu.  What kind of changes do you want to make on the fly?

Comment: There are different types of smart contracts can be. I want to check on the fly what the type of contract is in the current editor, and then show the user variants of interaction with it.